# Al ejecutar docker-compose run --rm web django-admin.py makemigrations clientprofile me da el siguiente error

Tags: python, django, docker

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/virtualenv/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 216, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 36, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.autodetector import MigrationAutodetector
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.questioner import MigrationQuestioner
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/questioner.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .loader import MigrationLoader
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 9, in <module>
    class MigrationRecorder:
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 22, in MigrationRecorder
    class Migration(models.Model):
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 100, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 244, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 127, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: Hola Carlos, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, para poder ayudarte, nos podrías mostrar el código que estas intentando realizar. Podrías editar un poco la pregunta.

Comment: Hola, claro que si.

Comment: Hola, cono gusto. Estoy ejecutando esta setencia sobre una imagen de Docker. Es para una base de datos en postgree para el objeto cliente. Esta es la sentencia que estoy usando =  docker-compose run --rm web django-admin.py makemigrations clientprofile

Comment: Parece que tu aplicación no carga bien las Apps antes de correr las migraciones. No sé a qué se deba bien pero intenta entrar primero al contenedor a debugear (`docker-compose exec web bash`) y por otro lado, si tu aplicación ya existe, para evitarte problemas con las variables de entorno y otras posibles configuraciones, es mejor usar `manage.py` en vez de `django-admin.py`. Mira [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220303/when-should-you-use-django-admin-py-verus-manage-py)

Comment: gracias Raul, pude solventar la migracion sobre la base de datos.